# How to convert GUI user string input in a format to make use of C++ library functions

Tags: c++, user-interface

Just for learning purposes, I'm writing a C++ program which has a GUI interface and contains a library of assorted functions, solvers etc. A user defines it's own set of instructions in a textfield. then this file would be parsed in a way the the underlying library will understand.

How would this work? would I parse the input into some form of machine level code? Can somebody provide a manner in which this can be organised from a C++ perspective or otherwise? I would find it inefficient for the underlying library itself would provide a set of parsing instructions.

So for example, if the user input this

```
's1 = 2;
s2 = 7;
s3 = 9;
x1' = s1 * x2 + s2;
x2' = s3 * x1'
```

I would generate something like this

```
constexpr double s1 = 2;
constexpr double s2 = 7;
constexpr double s3 = 9;
void ode_system(std::vector<double>& x_, std::vector<double>& y_)
{
    y_[0] = s1 * x_[1] + s2;
    y_[1] = s3 * x_[0];
}
```

how would this be compiled and linked with the libraries in a stand alone GUI if this is the correct way?

If not, what is the best way to achieve what I am doing?

**I ask this to save me from undeniable hell if I go down a wrong path! also for others as a reference**

As an example, you have programs like MATLAB (with a Java interface be it that) will parse your script into some object so it can use its built in library functions

Answer (score 0):

As you do not say exactly what the syntax of the *script file* is, it is hard to give you a precise advice. For what I understand of your question, I think you should :

- define the precise syntax of the input script file
- use a parser generator such as lex + yacc or its variant flex + bison to build routines to parse the file and convert it to *I cannot say before you say it first* (*)
- define the precise syntax of input GUI and the way you want to use the elements of the script
- if it is simple enough parse it directly or use again lex+yacc to build a parser
- glue all that together

(*) : you do not give enough elements to allow a precise answer - depending of the complexity of the expressions you want to process, you can simply have a set of routines that take their parameters from the input script : that's more of less what you called *convert it to* but I do not go down to machine level code

On the other hand if it is *really* complex or highly versatile, you can fully embed an interpreted language such as Python and have it directly execute the scripts with data coming from the GUI parser